# Get pid of a tab launched with selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, chromium, pid

i wrote a python script using selenium lib to launch an instance of chromium with several tab (in the same window). Now i have to identify the pid of a tab (that a match whith a selenium object into my script).
I found a way to retrive the parent pid and all their children but i can't associate them with a particular tab.

```
import psutil
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
parent = psutil.Process(browser.service.process.pid)
parent.children(recursive=True)
```

P.S. I can't use chromium task manager